# SEO - uso de keywords

Tags: html5, asp.net, seo

Algunos dicen que si una pagina web tiene contenido de 300 palabras, en el `meta tag keywords` no se puede tener mas de 30 palabras claves.

Mi dudas son:

1. Si mi pagina es un juego para niños, hecha puramente con imagenes,animaciones en css y **no tiene contenido de texto**, cuantas keywords puedo tener en el meta tag?
2. Estas keywords me ayudaran en el SEO si la pagina no tiene contenido texto?
3. Si tengo un listado con las siguentes palabras claves (por ejemplo):

   meta name="keywords" content="juegos para niños de 3, juegos para niños de 2, juegos para niños de 4"

Fijense que hay una parte de la palabra clave que se repite **"...juegos para niños..."**.

Entonces mi preguta es, me conviene poner esas palabras claves asi como estan, repitiendo la parte "juegos para niños". O conviene mas poner como palabra clave "juegos para niños" y despues agregarle otras palabras como "de 2", "de 3", "de 4", etc...

Comment: Google no las utiliza, pero ojo, otros buscadores sí, y aunque sean minoritarios siempre biene vien un poco de tráfico extra.
Yo personalmente no las pongo pero en algunos CMS como Prestashop tienes la opción muy presente y es rápido ponerlas.
Haz la prueba y analiza tu tráfico para ver si ganas tráfico de Bing o Yahoo.
Saludos.

Comment: Quieres usar las meta etiquetas porque hay gente que dice que google las tiene en cuenta, antes de hacer caso a google cuando dice que no ? Yo hace mil años que no las uso y he alcanzado bastantes primeros lugares en Google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay una respuesta muy clara a tu pregunta: **no te rompas la cabeza organizando keywords porque simplemente ¡ya no se usan!**

Te voy a traducir la publicación de Google, del año 2009, en la que se sustenta mi respuesta:

> Recientemente recibimos algunas preguntas sobre cómo Google usa (o más
>   exactamente, no usa) la metaetiqueta "palabras clave" para clasificar
>   los resultados de búsqueda web.
>
> Supongamos que tiene dos propietarios
>   de sitios web, Alice y Bob. Alice dirige una compañía llamada AliceCo
>   y Bob dirige BobCo. Un día, mientras miraba el sitio de Bob, Alice
>   nota que Bob ha copiado algunas de las palabras que usa en su
>   metaetiqueta de "palabras clave". Aún más interesante, Bob ha agregado
>   las palabras "AliceCo" a su metaetiqueta "keywords". ¿Debería
>   preocuparse Alice?
>
> Al menos para los resultados de búsqueda web de Google actualmente
>   (septiembre de 2009), la respuesta es no. **Google no utiliza la
>   metaetiqueta "palabras clave" en nuestro ranking de búsqueda web**...

---

En la misma página se formula la siguiente pregunta, con la respuesta de Google seguida de ella:

> **P: ¿Por qué Google no utiliza la metaetiqueta de palabras clave?**
>
> **R:** Hace aproximadamente una década, los motores de búsqueda juzgaban las páginas solo por el contenido de las páginas web, no por
>   los denominados factores "fuera de la página", como los enlaces que
>   apuntan a una página web. En aquellos días, las metaetiquetas de
>   palabras clave se convertían rápidamente en un área en la que alguien
>   podía incluir palabras clave irrelevantes a menudo sin que los
>   visitantes habituales vieran esas palabras clave. Debido a que se abusaba muy a menudo de dicha etiqueta, **hace muchos años que Google comenzó a ignorarla**.

#### ¿Y las otras meta etiquetas? ¿qué pasa con ellas?

La pregunta también fue planteada en el mismo sitio. Y la respuesta de Google es la siguiente:

> **P: ¿Esto significa que Google ignora todas las meta etiquetas?**
>
> **R:** No, Google admite varias metaetiquetas más. Esta página de metaetiquetas contiene más información sobre varias metaetiquetas que
>   usamos. Por ejemplo, algunas veces usamos la metaetiqueta
>   "description" (como se muestra en la imagen):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Aunque a veces utilizamos la metaetiqueta de descripción para los
>   fragmentos que mostramos, aún no usamos la metaetiqueta de descripción
>   en nuestro ranking.

La última pregunta/respuesta también es interesante. Hace pensar que, al menos para Google, la meta etiqueta `keywords` fue casi un mito:

> **P: ¿Esto significa que Google siempre ignorará la metaetiqueta de palabras clave?**
>
> R: Es posible que Google pueda usar esta información en el futuro,
>   pero es poco probable. [Google ha ignorado la metaetiqueta de palabras
>   clave durante años](http://searchengineland.com/meta-keywords-tag-101-how-to-legally-hide-words-on-your-pages-for-search-engines-12099) y actualmente no vemos la necesidad de cambiar
>   esa política.

- <sub>Fuente: [Google Webmasters Central Blog](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html). Artículo del 21 de septiembre de 2009. Algunas negritas añadidas por mi.</sub>

---

#### Pero... no todo es Google ¿no?. Están Yahoo, Bing y demás familiares.

Tampoco las usan. Las meta keywords no tienen hoy día ningún sentido.

Uno de los últimos en darse cuenta de ello fue Bing, quien publicaba esto en su blog en 2014, cinco años después que Google:

> Today, it’s pretty clear the meta keyword tag is dead in terms of SEO
>   value. Sure, it might have value for contextual ad systems or serve as
>   a signal to ‘bots plying the web looking for topics to target, but as
>   far as search goes, that tag flat lined years ago as a booster.
>
> ---
>
> Hoy en día, está bastante claro que **la meta etiqueta de palabra clave
>   está muerta en términos de valor SEO**. Claro, podría tener valor para
>   los sistemas de anuncios contextuales o servir como una señal para que
>   los robots naveguen por la web en busca de temas a los que apuntar,
>   pero en lo que respecta a la búsqueda, esa etiqueta plana... [Esa
>   última parte es intraducible para mi]

- <sub>Fuente: [Blog de Bing](https://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/2014/10/03/blame-the-meta-keyword-tag). 4 de octubre de 2014</sub>

---

### Orientar el SEO por otros rumbos

Espero que saber que las keywords ya no se usan sea una buena noticia para ti. En tu pregunta se plantea un serio problema para orientarse sobre el uso correcto de la meta etiqueta palabras claves.

Ahora puedes orientar tus técnicas SEO a cosas más concretas, entre ellas:

1. **Calidad** de tu contenido, bien escrito, usando concienzudamente los elementos que ofrece HTML sin abusar de ellos. Hablo de etiquetas como `strong`, `em`, `article`, etc.
2. Una buena meta **description**.
3. Palabras claves en la **URL**
4. Un buen **título**, con uso inteligente de las palabras que quieras resaltar, siempre relacionado con el contenido claro... sin hacer trampa.
5. Un buen resumen (excerpt)
6. La **antigüedad del dominio** también juega... por lo que la paciencia es fundamental en el SEO. Me atrevería a decir que aplicando esas pequeñas reglas, respetando los límites de palabras permitidos para cada caso... lo demás es cuestión de tiempo.

Hay otras cosas que tienen mucha influencia en el SEO, pero no dependen de ti directamente. Algo muy influyente es que tu sitio sea enlazado por otros sitios de importancia, con un ranking alto de SEO. Y hay más factores... Creo que con lo dicho se responde, con largueza, a tu duda inicial.

Comment: Ya habia leido esa noticia, pero hay mucha gente que dice que a pesar de esto google lo sigue usando, si no para que sigue existiendo google AdWords... Punto y a parte me gustaria hacerte otra pregunta, si ya no se usan keywords, que palabras tiene que poner en el buscador alguna persona que quiere encontrar mi sitio web?En que se basan ahora?

Comment: @OrenDiaz el SEO se basa en varias cosas, no se trata sólo de algo estratégico. Google ha desarrollado un algoritmo bastante potente que analiza no solamente posibles *trucos* que se implementaron durante años para *engañar* a los robots de Google. Ahora mismo el boot de Google es capaz hasta de penalizarte si encuentra incoherencias en tu sitio. Para un buen SEO: buen contenido (usando bien las negritas y nuevos elementos de HTML5), buenos títulos, buen excerpt, buena meta descripción respetando en cada uno los límites de palabras permitidos. Y la antigüedad del dominio tiene su peso.

Comment: Hay personas que las siguen utilizando, yo soy una de ellas. Te comento mis razones: Actualmente Google no las utiliza, pero nadie puede asegurar que no lo hará en un futuro ¿y si Google decidiera volver a utilizarlas?, tendrías que repasarte de nuevo todas las webs que tengas (o de clientes como es mi caso) e ir poniéndolas de nuevo. En un sitio web, no perderás mucho tiempo, pero si manejas muchos será una ardua tarea. Ponerlas no te robará mucho tiempo, mientras configuras otras propiedades del SEO.

Comment: @jonilgz por todo lo dicho en la respuesta queda claro que las keywords no tienen hoy día ningún sentido. No sigas soñando con la ilusión de que algún día un sitio subirá en SEO por una keyword. Se trata de escribir contenido de calidad, sitios fluídos, de fácil navegación, contenido bien organizado... Si lees bien, Google no tiene ninguna intención de volver a usarlas, y desde que dijeron aquello en 2009, hacía ya años que no las usaban ¿crees que en un área como esta que avanza a pasos agigantados se va a volver atrás? Y aunque así sea, podrías crear un script que las añadiera.

Comment: @A.Cedano No es cuestión de soñar que el sitio subirá por las meta-keywords ni por el contenido o algo en concreto, el SEO es un conjunto de criterios, y no por que cumplas uno de ellos tú web aparecerá en primera página si el resto son desastrosos. Tampoco es necesario que me vuelvas a resumir el SEO, es mi trabajo y me paso los días realizando pruebas e investigando. Sí mal no recuerdo, la filosofía de un buen SEO es probar y probar, no cerrarse puertas y quedarse con los mismos 3 parámetros: Contenido, velocidad de carga y URL, si te encierras en ello solo posicionarás simples criterios.